# Setting initial state of PrintPreviewDialog controls in App.config

Tags: wpf

I need to set the initial state of PrintPreviewDialog controls in App.config.
in case of loss of source code, here is the scenario:
Every time the user calls the print dialog it should open with 80% zoom instead of 100%

Comment: How are you showing a print preview?